# To access sortInfo attribute inside load function of data store of a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs) in one of my projects. I am using Extjs Grid. I that I have to access `sortInfo` attribue inside `load` function of my `Ext.data.store`.

Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
listeners : {
                load : function(store,records,options){
                            console.log(store.sortInfo);
                        }   
           }
```

refer : [Ext.data.Store.load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load)